# Use of Conscrypt library

Tags: cryptography, fips, boringssl, java-native-library, google-conscrypt

How to use conscrypt library in a way that we can use a boringCrypto module?
In conscrypt we have nativeCrypto class in that we have native methods present i have to utilize that methods for encryption and decryption in such a way that it is FIPS compliance.